# How is it possible to have four types of generating functions?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space

Since the Hamilton's equations of motion remain unchanged in form under a canonical transformation $(q,p)\to (Q,P)$, the Lagrangians must differ by a total time derivative of a function of $q,t$. In other words, $$L-L'=\frac{dF(q,t)}{dt}$$ 
$$\Rightarrow (p\dot{q}-H)-(P\dot{Q}-K)=\frac{dF(q,t)}{dt}$$ where $H(q,p,t)$ and $K(Q,P,t)$ are respectively the old and new Hamiltonians. How can there be four types of canonical transformations $$
(i)\ F_1(q,Q,t), \qquad (ii)\ F_2(q,P,t),\qquad (iii)\  F_3(p,Q,t),\qquad (iv)\  F_4(p,P,t)$$  if $F$ were to be a function of $q$ and $t$ only?

Answer (score 1):

OP's first formula applies to the Lagrangian formalism in [configuration space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_space_(physics)). In the context of [canonical transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_transformation) (CT), it must be replaced with the corresponding formula in Hamiltonian [phase space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_space), i.e. the generating function $F(q,p,t)$ is also allowed to depend on momenta $p$. Since the new phase space variables $(Q,P)$ are supposed to depend on the old phase space variables $(q,p)$ and time $t$, we may assume that the generating function $F(q,p,Q,P,t)$ depends on both new and old variables. The [four types of CT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_transformation#Type_1_generating_function) are special cases.